# While studying about inner class I found that I cannot use static methods inside the inner class.But dont know why this following code is not working

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

```java
package com.company;

public class TRY3 {

    static int n=5;
        public class New{
           int a;
            public New(int num){
                this.a=num;
            }

    }
    public class TRY3_Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TRY3.New obj1=new TRY3().new New(8);
            System.out.println(TRY3.n+obj1.a);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know we cannot write static methods inside inner classes...but in this code I have used main method(which is of course static) but not inside inner class ,I have used it as a part of outer class....than why this code is not running?

Comment: Your `main` method is inside an inner class called `Main`, which is inside another class called `TRY3`.

Comment: Now with your edit Main is still an inner class inside TRY3.

Comment: Your newest edit didn't change much. Now you have `public class TRY3_Main` which is an inner class of `public class TRY3`. Honestly, why don't you slow down, stop making rapid edits and take a moment to think about your question and what you really want to ask with what code example.

Comment: @khelwood now please check it once again....I have made some changes..still not working

Comment: from [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3-100): "*An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly static.*"  || `TRY3_Main` is a nested class since it is inside class `TRY3`; `TRY3_Main` is not `static`  --> `TRY3_Main` is an *inner class* ((Question: why is it implemented as a nested class? ))

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS ok thanks...actually its my first time here so not very familiar...

Comment: ... Yes, you've changed your inner class from `Main` to `TRY3_Main`. Was that supposed to fix something?

Comment: @user16320675 actually I hv done some mistakes...sorry...actually Try_Main was not there initially...please wait I hv to make some more corrections...

Comment: @khelwood thanks...its clear now...

Answer (score -1):

In your code you have mismatching graphs. See your code commented below:

```
package com.company;

public class TRY3 {// open graph for TRY3 class declaration

    static int n=5;
        public class New{ // open graph for New class declaration
           int a;
            public New(int num){ //open graph for New constructor (avoid names that can match keywords, they get confusing very fast
                this.a=num;
            } //closed graph for New constructor
}//closed graph for New class declaration

            public class Main { //open graph for Main class declaration
                public static void main(String[] args) { //open graph for main method
                    TRY3.New obj1=new TRY3().new New(8);
                    System.out.println(TRY3.n+obj1.a);
                }//closed graph for main method
            }//closed graph for Main class declaration
    }// closed graph for TRY3 class declaration
}// mismatched graph
```

What i suggest you to adopt when programming is indentation.
every graph that you open, you close it on the same level as the one you opened.
This is to avoid confusion between opening an closing graphs (as in this case).

also, you wrote:

> As far as I know we cannot write static methods inside inner classes.

This is true up to Java 15. In the case you are using Java 16 or later, you will be able to declare static methods in inner classes.

Source: [Java 16 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/16all-relnotes.html#JDK-8246771)

Comment: Note: "*CAN do static method in inner classes*" this is only valid starting with Java 16 - up to Java 15, the [JLS 8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3-130) stated: "**It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a member that is explicitly or implicitly static, unless the member is a constant variable**" - this was changed when Record Classes where added [Release Notes Java 16](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/16all-relnotes.html#JDK-8246771)

Comment: If i could upvote your comment i would! You learn things everyday! I shall edit my answer with your informations

Comment: The brackets *are* balanced. What you have tagged as *closed graph for TRY3 class declaration* is in fact the closing brace for the **New** class

Comment: They are not, just put the code on an IDE to check yourself